# C# datagridview math operation then pass data to a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datagridview, for-loop

I have a datagridview on my Winform GUI which loads a CSV and gathers data with three columns:

File_ID, Details, End Line
0, sometext, 1
0, sometext, 3
0, sometext, 5
1, sometext, 9
1, sometext, 16
1, sometext, 23
2, sometext, 25
2, sometext, 27
2, sometext, 28
2, sometext, 30

I want this gridview to be translated to a list
so that I can do something like this:

pList.Add(new FileExtract(1, 1, 148165));
pList.Add(new FileExtract(2, 148165, 166926));

but a loop rather than hardcording Add(new FileExtract ... )

The list should look something like this:
ID, start, end
1, 0, 5
2, 6, 23
3, 24, 30

Note that:
- For first line: ID = 1, start =  0.
- ID = 1 relates to File_ID, think of ID as counter
- Start on ID 2, is end of ID 1 plus 1, start on ID 3 = end of ID 2 plus

The bit that works:

```
                var filesplitc = from p in ListBoxEdit1
                             group p by p.file_id into grp
                             let MaxP = grp.Max(g => g.RunningTotal)
                             from p in grp
                             where p.RunningTotal == MaxP
                             select p;

            var filesplitc1 = from p in filesplitc
                              select new { file_id = p.file_id, startingline = (p.file_id == 0) ? "0" : "", endingline = p.RunningTotal  };
```

The bit that doesn't work:

```
            var filesplitc2 = from p in filesplitc1
                              select new { 
                                  file_id = p.file_id,
                                  startingline = p.startingline == "" ? ((from x in filesplitc1 where (Convert.ToInt32(x.file_id) <= Convert.ToInt32(p.file_id)) select x.endingline).Last()) : p.startingline,
                                  endingline = p.endingline 
                              };
```

Comment: Maybe you can show some code of what you have tried so far and where you got stuck with it.

Comment: When you say the bit that doesn't work, do you mean it yields incorrect results or it wont even compile? The IIF code line assigning startingline looks like it could do with another set of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to adjust it a bit because I don't know what data structure you put into the list box but should give you an idea. It's not Linq but trying to squash everything into a Linq query does not necessarily help readability and code maintenance.

```
class FileExtract
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}


var fileExtracts = new List<FileExtract>();
// take first entry as initializer
var current = new FileExtract 
              { 
                  FileId = ListBoxEdit1.First().file_id, 
                  Start = 0, 
                  End = ListBoxEdit1.First().end_line
              };
int lastEnd = current.End;
// skip first entry of the list as it was already used as initializer
foreach (var p in ListBoxEdit1.Skip())
{
    if (current.FileId != p.file_id)
    {
        current.End = lastEnd;
        fileExtract.Add(current);
        current = new FileExtract { FileId = p.file_id, Start = lastEnd + 1, End = p.end_line };          
    }
    lastEnd = p.end_line;
}
```